# como puedo hacer que la suma se imprima en el h1

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Quiero hacer que la suma su resultado se dé en el h1, no sé si se pueda con inner.html o textcontent

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
        <div>
                <button class="buton" id="pin1.4">texto1</button>
              </div>
            <div>
            <button class="buton" id="pin2.4">texto2</button>
          </div>
            <div>
            <button class="buton" id="pin3.4">texto3</button>
   </div>
   <DIV>
        <input  class="buton" type="button" id="boton_calc" value="Sumar">
      </div>
   <p><h1>aqui va la suma</h1></p>
<script>
     var boton_numero1 = document.getElementById("pin1.4");
    var boton_numero2 = document.getElementById("pin2.4");
    var boton_numero3 = document.getElementById("pin3.4");

    var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("boton_calc");

        boton_numero1.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor);
        boton_numero2.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor2);
        boton_numero3.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor3);

        boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", Sumar);
var n1 = 0;
var n2 = 0;
var n3 = 0;
function cambio_valor() {
  n1 = 53;
}
function cambio_valor2() {
  n2 = 43;
}
function cambio_valor3() {
  n3 = 104;
}
function Sumar() {
  var suma = n1 + n2 + n3;
  alert("La suma de: " + n1 + " + " + n2 + " + " + n3 + " es igual a " + suma);
document.write(suma);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con `innerHTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
        <div>
                <button class="buton" id="pin1.4">texto1</button>
              </div>
            <div>
            <button class="buton" id="pin2.4">texto2</button>
          </div>
            <div>
            <button class="buton" id="pin3.4">texto3</button>
   </div>
   <div>
        <input  class="buton" type="button" id="boton_calc" value="Sumar">
      </div>
   <h1 id="resultado">aqui va la suma</h1>
<script>
     var boton_numero1 = document.getElementById("pin1.4");
    var boton_numero2 = document.getElementById("pin2.4");
    var boton_numero3 = document.getElementById("pin3.4");

    var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("boton_calc");

        boton_numero1.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor);
        boton_numero2.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor2);
        boton_numero3.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor3);

        boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", Sumar);
var n1 = 0;
var n2 = 0;
var n3 = 0;
function cambio_valor() {
  n1 = 53;
}
function cambio_valor2() {
  n2 = 43;
}
function cambio_valor3() {
  n3 = 104;
}
function Sumar() {
  var suma = n1 + n2 + n3;
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML="La suma es " + suma;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```